# VPN on my home W7 HTPC

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I would like to install an sstp vpn on my HTPC (win7 pro). (I choose sstp over pptp since I heard that it is not secure anymore).
I want to do that to be able to be able to see all the shared folders of any computer in my home when outside of it. (I want it to be compatible with my surface RT, that's why I don't want openVPN :()

I only found tutorial for windows server, and not win7.

So, I was wondering, is it possible to do that on a win7 computer ?

Thanks

Comment: It should work fine, what's the link to the instructions you've found?  If we had that information we'd be able to give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step by step guide to setting up a VPN via SSTP.

Go to `Network and Sharing Center`

[image]

Go to `Set up a new connection or network`

[image]

Select `Connect to a workplace` and press next

[image]

Select `Use my Internet connection (VPN)`

[image]

Enter your site information, give it a destination name. Make sure `Don't connect now` is checked. We will need to set up security first.

[image]

Enter your username and password. Press `Create`

[image]

Now you will see your VPN listed. Right click it and go to `Properties`

[image]

Go to the `Security` tab, select `SSTP` from the `Type of VPN` Dropdown.

[image]

You can set up other settings in this tab as well (MS-CHAP etc) Press Ok and then connect

Depending on your settings, you may need to then connect via remote desktop using your computers IP address in order to gain access to it, right now your just connecting through it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is more about setting this up on the win7 server :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question then, are you trying to allow VPN connections to your windows 7 server or are you trying to connect to a VPN via a windows 7 server?

Comment: to my windows7 server

Comment: Then this will work assuming your server is configured to allow incoming connections. Refer to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753616(v=ws.10).aspx) if you have not already configured your server